# Twilio Check the Verification Token API+postman timeout

Tags: node.js, twilio, postman

I am setting up phone authentication with Twilio, using nodejs....All is working as expected, except when verifying the token. Below is the function which I am using:

```
verifyPhone: function (req, res) {


        client.verify.services('VAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
            .verificationChecks
            .create({ to: '+15017122661', code: '123456' })
            .then(function (err, verification_check) {

              if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
              } else if (verification_check ==='approved') {
                res.status(200).send('Account Verified');
              }

            })  

    }
```

I am checking the endpoint in postman, and it is timing out with no response.

When, I checked in twilio portal, the number status changed to approved.

Any idea why the response is not showing up.

Btw, I turned off SSL certificate

Thanks,

Comment: It is not clear from your question what do you do when `checking the endpoint in postman` and if the status change is the result of Postman request or executing the function.

Comment: thanks, I have deleted the service from twilio admin, and added a new one....the same code has been executed, and I got a result in postman...many thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twilio Function JavaScript below works for me.

Since Verify v2 is relatively new, make sure your Twilio Helper library is up to date, https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/releases.

Example to execute function (I have Check for valid Twilio signature turned off for my Twilio function to demo this):

(Example URL to Run Function):
https://mango-abcdef-1234.twil.io/v2start?phoneNumber=%2b15555551234&code=720732

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const client = context.getTwilioClient();   
    const code = event.code;
    let phoneNumber = event.phoneNumber;
    client.verify.services('VAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
             .verificationChecks
             .create({to: phoneNumber, code: code})
             .then(verification_check => {
                 console.log(`***VERIFICATION STATUS***: ${verification_check.status}`);
                 callback(null, `${verification_check.status}`);
             })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                  callback();
              });
};
```

Also recent blog on this topic.

[Serverless Phone Verification with Twilio Verify and Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/blog/serverless-phone-verification)

Comment: I have deleted the service from twilio admin, and added a new one....the same code has been executed, and I got a result in postman...many thanks for your support